# Unable to start Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I'm trying to start Tomcat in Netbeans, unfortunately it is stuck at "org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 793 ms". After a while I get an error message popup saying that starting Tomcat failed. I'm using Mac OS

This is all the output I see:

```
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.328 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.15
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.329 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 2 2014 19:25:20 UTC
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.329 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.15.0
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.329 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.329 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.10.1
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.329 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86_64
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.329 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JAVA_HOME:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.330 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.7.0_25-b15
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.330 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.330 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/Exceen/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.0.2/apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.330 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /Applications/NetBeans/apache-tomcat-8.0.15
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.331 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/Exceen/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.0.2/apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base/conf/logging.properties
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.331 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.331 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Applications/NetBeans/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/endorsed
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.331 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/Exceen/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.0.2/apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.331 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Applications/NetBeans/apache-tomcat-8.0.15
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.331 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/Exceen/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.0.2/apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base/temp
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.332 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.0.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/webcommon/bin::/Users/Exceen/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.479 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.503 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.511 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.513 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.517 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 696 ms
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.586 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.586 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.15
29-Jan-2015 11:42:53.599 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor /Users/Exceen/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.0.2/apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
29-Jan-2015 11:42:54.127 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
29-Jan-2015 11:42:54.196 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor /Users/Exceen/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.0.2/apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml has finished in 596 ms
29-Jan-2015 11:42:54.196 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor /Users/Exceen/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.0.2/apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
29-Jan-2015 11:42:54.297 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
29-Jan-2015 11:42:54.299 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor /Users/Exceen/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.0.2/apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml has finished in 103 ms
29-Jan-2015 11:42:54.303 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
29-Jan-2015 11:42:54.310 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
29-Jan-2015 11:42:54.311 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 793 ms
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Aren't you getting any exception

Comment: There is no error information in the logs which you have posted. post us with full logs

Comment: This is the full log and I don't get any exception.

Comment: its already running. try go to your localhost in browser

Comment: Not it is not. If I try to run a program it says after ~3 minutes "Starting of Tomcat failed."

Comment: "Server startup in 793 ms". If you are still getting a timeout, reinstall Netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the fix by editing `server.xml` and adding `server="XXXXXXX"`, where `XXXXXXX` should be the same name as web server found in `netbeans`.

For example, `server="Apache Tomcat or TomEE"`

Comment: But where in the server.xml file ```server="Apache Tomcat"``` need to be added?

Answer (score 1):

Check in your web browser, if after starting tomcat you can reach localhost (if you haven't changed port number, it's under: http://localhost:8080/).

If it works:
- There is problem with application- server communication (Have you properly deployed your app? Is there any firewall, which might block your app from running?)

If not:
Tomcat is configured incorrectly. You might try to start it outside Netbeans (e.g. in console) to see if it works. If not, reinstall Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Try something:

- Enter your web application path correctly, manually in web browser address bar.

- Because IDE don't know start path. Or you must set up `<welcome-files-list>` element in `web.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but this solves the problem:

> Hi,  I just want to point out an observation.  I discovered that
>   starting tomee 1.7.2 (plus) as a server in netbeans, netbeans is not
>   too happy about the server="Apache TomEE" config on the 8080
>   connector.  So by removing this one startup is OK again.
>
> I guess a bug in the netbeans tomee (and tomcat) extention.

(founded here: http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/netbeans-annoyance-td4675134.html )

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me on my mac.

The cause was network change => I set static IP on network settings.

Answer (score 0):

Had a problem with the same symptoms, turned out manager.xml was missing from CATALINA_BASE/conf/localhost, so Tomcat's manager app wasn't starting so Netbeans couldn't talk to it. Installing a manager.xml file with following contents fixed the problem:

```
<Context docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager" antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers helped for me and nothing was logged anywhere either, so I went the long way and debugged NetBeans in the Java debugger to find out what was going wrong. It made me discover that NetBeans was denied a TCP socket connection to the Tomcat Manager webapp, which made it falsely assume Tomcat wasn't alive.

Solution:

Add

```
-J-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

to the command line options in netbeans.conf file (key "netbeans_default_options").

If this still doesn't help for you, you can set a breakpoint in org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.util.Utils#pingTomcat() and trace what's happening from there.

Answer (score 0):

In my Windows machine, I solved the problem using the following links:

https://geekflare.com/tomcat-stuck-at-startup/

**Summary of the link:**

1. Go to Tomcat installation folder and then bin
2. Open catalina.sh using the vi editor
3. Search for JAVA_OPTS and add the following

> -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
> 4. Save the file and restart Tomcat